# How to mute/control WebView/Flash volume?

Tags: android, flash, android-webview

I play Flash in a webview.
Is it possible to mute the animation sound?

My activity could also play music files, so I set:

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

Is it somehow related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to mute the sound of any stream of your device, use

```
public void setStreamMute (int streamType, boolean state)
```

Example :

```
myAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setStreamMute I used setStreamVolume, to be able to set volume to max when unmutting volume=0

```
    /**
 * Set sound state
 * @param soundOn new sound state
 */
private void setSoundState(boolean soundOn) {
    // set sound param
    mGlobalData.SoundOn = soundOn;
    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    if (soundOn) {
        // restore old volume
        int newVoume = mGlobalData.oldSoundVolume;

        if (newVoume == 0)
            newVoume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mSoundIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,newVoume, 0);

        //mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 1);
    } else {
        mSoundIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
        mGlobalData.oldSoundVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0, 0);
        //mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
    }
}
```